# How to calculate the value of Net Salary?

Tags: c#, gridview

This is my grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
OnPageIndexChanging="gridview1_PageIndexChanging" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
OnDataBound="gridview1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="gridview1_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true"
PageSize="20" ShowFooter="true" Style="font-size: small; font-family: Verdana;">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Staff No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblsno" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Staff_No") %>'>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gross Salary">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblGS" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GROSS_SALARY") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblaccno" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("acc_num") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gridview2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true"
                    PageSize="10" ShowFooter="true" Style="font-size: small; font-family: Verdana;">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="E.P.F">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblepf" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("epf") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblnewepf" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Salary">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblns" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblnewns" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As you can see, in the first grid view (gridview1) it has another grid view (gridview2). This is my table:
[image]

Value for Net Salary = Gross Salary - E.P.F.

How to calculate the value of Net Salary?

Comment: Compute the net salary in code behind (handle RowDataBound event to assign value of net salary to control property)

Comment: this is barely a programming question, you are asking someone else to do you job for you given a hunk of code

Comment: I'm not asking someone to do my job. I already try many solutions and search the example in the internet but all I got is an error. I ask my friend about this but they didn't how, but thank you for taking your time read my question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following in the .ASPX file.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Salary">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblns" runat="server" Text='<%# GetNetSalary(Eval("GROSS_SALARY"),Eval("epf")) %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblnewns" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

In the .CS file add this

```
private string GetNetSalary(object grossSalary,object epf)
{
return (grossSalary - epf).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking your time to read my question. I already got a solution.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Salary">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblns" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("GROSS_SALARY")) - ConvertToDouble(Eval("epf")) %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblnewns" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```